# Best way to display number of check-boxes checked and unchecked based on database value

Tags: php, jsp, checkbox

I have 50 checkboxes in a page, say this page is used by a doctor to manage his patients data, So some checkboxes can be checked, some can be unchecked. I have a database table and separate columns for each this 50 checkboxes, with unchecked value 0 and checked value 1.

and in my display page , I have two ideas to make this checkboxes checked/unchecked, but both look crappy.

1.

```
   <% if(fieldOneChecked==1){%>
    <input type="checkbox" value='' name="fieldOne" checked="checked"/>
   <% }else{%>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fieldOne" value=''/>
  <%  }%>
```

2

```
<%
String foo=""
 if(fieldOneChecked==1){String foo="checked=\"checked\"";}
 %>
<input type="checkbox" name="fieldOne" value='' <%=foo%>/>
```

I have to repeat the same for 50 checkboxes.

Is there any better and easier way? Either in jsp or php, a better logic is what I want. :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple, Fast, Elegant (IMHO)

All this code is tested 100%.

### Fast? 200 mS Round Trip with all Checkboxes Checked

This is a screen shot from FireFox Inspector Network Tab.  Real Life Real Fast.  On an 18 mbs U-Verse Connection.

[image: FireFox Page Timing]

[image: HTTP Response Parameters]

I have used this in many production web apps.

### Production App with 5,500 Check Boxes

I have one mp3 player web app.  The check boxes are used to create a play list.  The list of songs is the top 100 Billboard songs for years 1960 through 2014, 5,500 songs.

This App loads all 5,500 check boxes in 55 divs. Only 100 are visible at a time.

[image: Billboard Top 10 1974]

---

First off I think check boxes are too small especially when viewed on a mobile device. I make them 2em wide and high.  Easier to see and bigger target for the cursor.

For improved visibility I encapsulate the check box in a div to color the background.  Once color for checked and one color for unchecked.

```
<?php  ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=84600');
header('Vary: Accept-Encoding'); 
echo <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><title>Testbed</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<style type="text/css">
body{background:#333;}
.row{height:2.2em;width:10em;color:#fff;font:700 1em Arial,sans-serif;display:inline-block;margin:.2em;}
input[type="radio"],input[type="checkbox"]{width:2em;height:2em;border:2px solid #eee;outline:2px solid #eee;display: inline;margin:.3em;vertical-align: middle;position: relative;background:#144;color:#eee;   display: inline;vertical-align: middle;position: relative;}   
.btn{border:1px solid #2985EA;color: #fff;background-color:#2985EA;
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #2ef 0%, #02f 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #2ef 0%, #02f 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #2ef 0%, #02f 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #2ef 0%, #02f 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2ef 0%, #02f 100%);
width:100%;padding: .5em;margin:.5em 0 0 0;border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;font: 700 1em Arial,Helvetica,Calibri,sans-serif;overflow: visible;}

</style></head><body><div id="page">
<form action="#" method="post"><div>
EOT;
ob_flush();
```

$checks = array_fill(0,50,0);  // initialize all 50 check boxes to zero
$sub = intval($_POST['sub']);

### Get Submitted Checked Boxes

```
if($sub == 1){
  foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
    if(substr($k,0,3) == 'chk'){  // is it a check box?
      $checked[$v] = 'checked="checked"'; // embedded in HTML checkbox tag
      $checks[$v] = 1;            // If checked, change value to 1
    }
  }
```

### Create SQL UPDATE

```
  $sql = "UPDATE `checkboxes` SET ";  // beginning of SQL INSERT query
  foreach($checks as $key => $value){
    $sql .= "`c$key`=$value,";    // concatenate SET checked values
  }
  $sql = substr($sql,0,-1) . ' WHERE `id` = 1'; // remove trailing comma and append WHERE
  msqli_query($link,$sql);
}
```

### Get Checked Boxes from SQL

```
else{
  $check = array('','checked="checked"');
  $sql = "SELECT `c0`, `c1`, `c2`, `c3`, `c4`, `c5`, `c6`, `c7`, `c8`, `c9`, `c10`, `c11`, `c12`, `c13`, `c14`, `c15`, `c16`, `c17`, `c18`, `c19`, `c20`, `c21`, `c22`, `c23`, `c24`, `c25`, `c26`, `c27`, `c28`, `c29`, `c30`, `c31`, `c32`, `c33`, `c34`, `c35`, `c36`, `c37`, `c38`, `c39`, `c40`, `c41`, `c42`, `c43`, `c44`, `c45`, `c46`, `c47`, `c48`, `c49` FROM `checkboxes` WHERE `id`=1";
  $result = msqli_query($link,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
  foreach($row as $key => $value){
    $checked[$key] = $check[$value] ; // embedded in HTML checkbox tag
    $checks[$key] = $value;            // If checked, change value to 1
  }
}
```

### Create HTML Checkboxes

```
for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){$divs[] = $i;}  // Create 50 HTML check boxes
foreach($divs as $key => $val){
  echo <<<EOT
<div id="d$key" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c$key" name="chk$key" value="$key" onclick="ck($key)" $checked[$key]/>&#x2002;Checkbox #$key
</div>
EOT;
}
```

---

**Hidden INPUT to indicate check boxes were submitted**

```
echo <<<EOT
<br/><button class="btn">Submit</button>

<input type="hidden" name="sub" value="1" />

</div></form></div>
```

### JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var c = new Array;
var d = new Array;
toggle = new Array;
toggle[true] = 'checked="checked"';
toggle[false] = '';
bg = new Array;
bg[true] = '#f00';
bg[false] = '#2985EA';
```

### Change Color when Check Box Checked or Unchecked

```
function ck(id){ 
  var div = document.getElementById('d' + id);
  var checked = document.getElementById('c' + id).checked;
  div.style.backgroundColor = bg[checked];
}
```

### The Init Function

On load the init() function colors the check boxes based on wheter they are checked or not.

```
function init(){
var checked,did;
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for (div=0; div<divs.length; div++){
    did = divs[div].getAttribute("id");
    if (did != null){
      if (did.substring(0,1) == "d"){
        var i = did.substring(1,5);
        c[i] = document.getElementById('c' + i);
        d[i] = document.getElementById('d' + i);
        checked = c[i].checked;
        d[i].style.backgroundColor=bg[checked];
      }
    }
  }
}

window.onload = init;
//]]>
</script></body></html>
EOT;
?>
```

---

### SQL Checkbox Test Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `checkboxes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`c0` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c1` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c3` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c4` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c5` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c6` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c7` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c8` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c9` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c10` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c11` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c12` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c13` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c14` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c15` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c16` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c17` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c18` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c19` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c20` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c21` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c22` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c23` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c24` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c25` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c26` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c27` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c28` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c29` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c30` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c31` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c32` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c33` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c34` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c35` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c36` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c37` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c38` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c39` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c40` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c41` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c42` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c43` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c44` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c45` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c46` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c47` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c48` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c49` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `checkboxes` (`id`, `c0`, `c1`, `c2`, `c3`, `c4`, `c5`, `c6`, `c7`, `c8`, `c9`, `c10`, `c11`, `c12`, `c13`, `c14`, `c15`, `c16`, `c17`, `c18`, `c19`, `c20`, `c21`, `c22`, `c23`, `c24`, `c25`, `c26`, `c27`, `c28`, `c29`, `c30`, `c31`, `c32`, `c33`, `c34`, `c35`, `c36`, `c37`, `c38`, `c39`, `c40`, `c41`, `c42`, `c43`, `c44`, `c45`, `c46`, `c47`, `c48`, `c49`) VALUES (NULL, '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0');
```

### Snippet

This Snippet was created with the above PHP by viewing source and doing a copy and paste.  The I manually added the `checked="checked"`

```js
var c = new Array;
var d = new Array;
toggle = new Array;
toggle[true] = 'checked="checked"';
toggle[false] = '';
bg = new Array;
bg[true] = '#f00';
bg[false] = '#2985EA';
function ck(id){ 
  var div = document.getElementById('d' + id);
  var checked = document.getElementById('c' + id).checked;
  div.style.backgroundColor = bg[checked];
}
function init(){
var checked,did;
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for (div=0; div<divs.length; div++){
    did = divs[div].getAttribute("id");
    if (did != null){
      if (did.substring(0,1) == "d"){
        var i = did.substring(1,5);
  d[i] = document.getElementById('d' + i).style.backgroundColor=bg[document.getElementById('c' + i).checked];

      }
    }
  }
}



window.onload = init;
```

```css
body{background:#333;}
.row{height:2.2em;width:10em;color:#fff;font:700 1em Arial,sans-serif;display:inline-block;margin:.2em;}
input[type="radio"],input[type="checkbox"]{width:2em;height:2em;border:2px solid #eee;outline:2px solid #eee;display: inline;margin:.3em;vertical-align: middle;position: relative;background:#144;color:#eee;   display: inline;vertical-align: middle;position: relative;}   
.btn{border:1px solid #2985EA;color: #fff;background-color:#2985EA;
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #2ef 0%, #02f 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #2ef 0%, #02f 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #2ef 0%, #02f 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #2ef 0%, #02f 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2ef 0%, #02f 100%);
width:100%;padding: .5em;margin:.5em 0 0 0;border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;font: 700 1em Arial,Helvetica,Calibri,sans-serif;overflow: visible;}
```

```html
<div id="page">
<form action="#" method="post"><div><div id="d0" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c0" name="chk0" value="0" onclick="ck(0)" checked="checked"/>&#x2002;Checkbox #0
</div><div id="d1" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="chk1" value="1" onclick="ck(1)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #1
</div><div id="d2" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="chk2" value="2" onclick="ck(2)" checked="checked"/>&#x2002;Checkbox #2
</div><div id="d3" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c3" name="chk3" value="3" onclick="ck(3)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #3
</div><div id="d4" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c4" name="chk4" value="4" onclick="ck(4)"checked="checked" />&#x2002;Checkbox #4
</div><div id="d5" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c5" name="chk5" value="5" onclick="ck(5)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #5
</div><div id="d6" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c6" name="chk6" value="6" onclick="ck(6)" checked="checked"/>&#x2002;Checkbox #6
</div><div id="d7" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c7" name="chk7" value="7" onclick="ck(7)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #7
</div><div id="d8" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c8" name="chk8" value="8" onclick="ck(8)" checked="checked" />&#x2002;Checkbox #8
</div><div id="d9" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c9" name="chk9" value="9" onclick="ck(9)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #9
</div><div id="d10" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c10" name="chk10" value="10" onclick="ck(10)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #10
</div><div id="d11" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c11" name="chk11" value="11" onclick="ck(11)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #11
</div><div id="d12" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c12" name="chk12" value="12" onclick="ck(12)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #12
</div><div id="d13" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c13" name="chk13" value="13" onclick="ck(13)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #13
</div><div id="d14" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c14" name="chk14" value="14" onclick="ck(14)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #14
</div><div id="d15" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c15" name="chk15" value="15" onclick="ck(15)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #15
</div><div id="d16" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c16" name="chk16" value="16" onclick="ck(16)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #16
</div><div id="d17" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c17" name="chk17" value="17" onclick="ck(17)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #17
</div><div id="d18" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c18" name="chk18" value="18" onclick="ck(18)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #18
</div><div id="d19" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c19" name="chk19" value="19" onclick="ck(19)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #19
</div><div id="d20" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c20" name="chk20" value="20" onclick="ck(20)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #20
</div><div id="d21" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c21" name="chk21" value="21" onclick="ck(21)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #21
</div><div id="d22" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c22" name="chk22" value="22" onclick="ck(22)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #22
</div><div id="d23" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c23" name="chk23" value="23" onclick="ck(23)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #23
</div><div id="d24" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c24" name="chk24" value="24" onclick="ck(24)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #24
</div><div id="d25" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c25" name="chk25" value="25" onclick="ck(25)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #25
</div><div id="d26" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c26" name="chk26" value="26" onclick="ck(26)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #26
</div><div id="d27" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c27" name="chk27" value="27" onclick="ck(27)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #27
</div><div id="d28" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c28" name="chk28" value="28" onclick="ck(28)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #28
</div><div id="d29" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c29" name="chk29" value="29" onclick="ck(29)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #29
</div><div id="d30" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c30" name="chk30" value="30" onclick="ck(30)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #30
</div><div id="d31" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c31" name="chk31" value="31" onclick="ck(31)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #31
</div><div id="d32" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c32" name="chk32" value="32" onclick="ck(32)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #32
</div><div id="d33" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c33" name="chk33" value="33" onclick="ck(33)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #33
</div><div id="d34" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c34" name="chk34" value="34" onclick="ck(34)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #34
</div><div id="d35" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c35" name="chk35" value="35" onclick="ck(35)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #35
</div><div id="d36" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c36" name="chk36" value="36" onclick="ck(36)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #36
</div><div id="d37" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c37" name="chk37" value="37" onclick="ck(37)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #37
</div><div id="d38" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c38" name="chk38" value="38" onclick="ck(38)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #38
</div><div id="d39" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c39" name="chk39" value="39" onclick="ck(39)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #39
</div><div id="d40" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c40" name="chk40" value="40" onclick="ck(40)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #40
</div><div id="d41" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c41" name="chk41" value="41" onclick="ck(41)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #41
</div><div id="d42" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c42" name="chk42" value="42" onclick="ck(42)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #42
</div><div id="d43" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c43" name="chk43" value="43" onclick="ck(43)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #43
</div><div id="d44" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c44" name="chk44" value="44" onclick="ck(44)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #44
</div><div id="d45" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c45" name="chk45" value="45" onclick="ck(45)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #45
</div><div id="d46" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c46" name="chk46" value="46" onclick="ck(46)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #46
</div><div id="d47" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c47" name="chk47" value="47" onclick="ck(47)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #47
</div><div id="d48" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c48" name="chk48" value="48" onclick="ck(48)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #48
</div><div id="d49" class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="c49" name="chk49" value="49" onclick="ck(49)" />&#x2002;Checkbox #49
</div><br/><button class="btn">Submit</button>
</div></form></div>
```

Comment: Your welcome.  There should be no problems, I think I covered every conceivable issue.  I have many apps using the technique.  If you have any problems or I did not cover something you need, I can help.  Every bit of the posted code is tested except populating the check boxes from the SQL.  Should work.  I plan to test it soon.  I spent a few hours writing this.  I did a lot of editing and there is a small possibility I may not have copy and pasted everything from my working testbed version.   I tested the update of the SQL from the submitted check boxes.